Update a table column based on match from other column in SQL
I have two tables "table1" and "table2". I want to update table1.PrespI with table2.RespI if table2.EmailId equals table2.EmailId else update table1.PrespI with table2.RespI(any RespI) where table2.BId equals table2.BId and table2.EL equals L
table1



EL
UniqueId
RespDt
RespI
PrespI




E
cd4fbc4a-a303-42b6-858a-5639525a20e3
2024-03-13
1234567
NULL


E
dd94ae32-2e22-4969-8e37-6f7711050df7
2024-03-13
6598456
NULL


E
570e1a04-b5b8-4a8e-bbc8-588c3157b9a4
2024-03-13
3594685
NULL



table2



BId
UniqueId
EmailId
RespDt
EL
RespI




123
cd4fbc4a-a303-42b6-858a-5639525a20e3
abc@test.com
2024-03-13
E
1234567


123
cd4fbc4a-a303-42b6-858a-5639525a20e3
abc@test.com
2023-03-13
L
8945632


123
3206a0a4-9859-4a97-92a0-602b527896df
dgh@test.com
2023-03-13
L
7798653


541
570e1a04-b5b8-4a8e-bbc8-588c3157b9a4
clr@test.com
2024-03-13
E
3594685


541
88960021-c6b7-48bf-8421-20fa63296b7d
def@test.com
2023-03-13
L
4681256


541
0b0fb857-6eb7-4f67-8672-813331b5224e
hkr@test.com
2023-03-13
L
0235489


876
dd94ae32-2e22-4969-8e37-6f7711050df7
plc@test.com
2024-03-13
E
6598456



expected



EL
UniqueId
RespDt
RespI
PrespI




E
cd4fbc4a-a303-42b6-858a-5639525a20e3
2024-03-13
1234567
8945632


E
dd94ae32-2e22-4969-8e37-6f7711050df7
2024-03-13
6598456
NULL


E
570e1a04-b5b8-4a8e-bbc8-588c3157b9a4
2024-03-13
3594685
4681256



I have this query but this only updates the matching records.
UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.PrespI = t3.RespI 
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2 on t1.UniqueId = t2.UniqueId and t2.EL = 'E' 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t3 on t2.BId = t3.BId and t3.EL = 'L' 
WHERE t2.EmailId = t3.EmailId;

If I remove the where clause t2.EmailId = t3.EmailId, than it will always update any random value where BId matches but I want that if email matches then update by email else any random value where BId matches and EL is L

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/SLML0aQq

table1.BId does not exist

Hi @BartMcEndree, thanks for the reply and I have corrected the question.

Your edit does not make sense. We now have table2.BId equals table2.BId. Maybe you mean  table1.UniqueId equals table2.UniqueId?

If we go on basis of UniqueId then table1.PrespI last row will never get filled

Typically this sort of pick one or the other matches uses outer joins to ensure that it handles rows that have no match in one or more tables. If there is some additional ordering information in how the matches are performed rather than "any RespI", you'll have to provide the rules.

If you move the t2.EL = 'E' join condition into the WHERE clause then you can construct a filter condition that matches your requirements.
UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.PrespI = t3.RespI 
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2 on t1.UniqueId = t2.UniqueId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t3 on t2.BId = t3.BId and t3.EL = 'L' 
WHERE (t2.EmailId = t3.EmailId AND  t2.EL = 'E')

UPDATE t1 
    SET t1.PrespI = t3.RespI 
FROM dbo.table1 AS t1 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t2 on t1.UniqueId = t2.UniqueId 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 AS t3 on t2.BId = t3.BId and t3.EL = 'L' 
WHERE  t2.EmailId <> t3.EmailId  AND  PrespI IS NULL

SELECT * FROM table1;

fiddle



EL
UniqueId
RespDt
RespI
PrespI




E
cd4fbc4a-a303-42b6-858a-5639525a20e3
2024-03-13
1234567
8945632


E
dd94ae32-2e22-4969-8e37-6f7711050df7
2024-03-13
6598456
null


E
570e1a04-b5b8-4a8e-bbc8-588c3157b9a4
2024-03-13
3594685
4681256




Thanks, but this doesn't work if we swap 2nd & 3rd row in table2, data could be any way.

Update split into 2 steps to avoid updating Prespl if it is already populated by 1st update.
